# phonegap installation fails due to package failure on https://github.com/ariya/esprima/tarball/master

Tags: node.js, cordova

I have an error when installing phonegap.

I have a problem with the https://github.com/ariya/esprima/tarball/master package, as it cannot be installed.

I have changed many different registries but all failed on the esprima module.

I even download the exact tarball manually from github and executed the following on the local filesystem:

```
npm install file_url
```

There is no sign of failure but "phonegap" command cannot still be used.

Please tell me how to install the failed module and finally get phonegap to work?

Thank you very much!